# How to check if there is NO command line arguments in C

Tags: c, command, calculator, argv, argc

I am creating simple calculator. I give arguments to be calculated as command line arguments.

How do check if user gave no arguments at all?

I Tried this, but i get segmentation fault:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if(argc == 0){
        printf("No arguments were given");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I Tried this, but i get segmentation fault:" --> Above code does not compile.  Best to post true code.

Comment: Typo: Close the braces

Comment: You want something like `if (argc < 4) { fprintf(stderr, "Usage: program num op num\n"); exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); }` is important to exit, otherwise you access uninitialized values in the next lines.

Comment: If there are no arguments, then your program prints "You did not give any arguments" and then immediately tries to read `*(argv[2])` which leads to undefined behavior that manifests itself as a segmentation fault.

Comment: If you have a new question then ask it *as* a new question.  Do not modify your existing question to something different, especially after you have received answers.  Rolled back.

Answer (score 2):

`argc` is the count of the program name and its arguments.

When `argc == 1`, there is only the program name and no additional arguments.

It is possible for `argc == 0` as that implies even the program name is not passed in.

**Test against 1**

```
if (argc <= 1) {
  printf("No arguments were given.\n");
}
```

**i get segmentation fault:**

This is certainly due to unposted parts of OP's code.